# How can I make my Embeds more Cleaner in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, embed

I would like to know how I can make my embeds more look more cleaner. The embed style I am using is like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("The Commands")
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .addField("Category:", "`something`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something1`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something2`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something3`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something4`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something5`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something6`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something7`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something8`", true)
        .addField("Category 1:", "`something9`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something10`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something11`", true)
        .addField("Category 2", "`something12`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something13`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something14`", true)
        .addField('\u200b', "`something15`", true);

        message.author.send(Embed)
        message.channel.send(`check your dm's for the commands`);
```

The outcome of this code is:
[image: This image is currently unavailable]

Here is somewhat closer to what I want the embed to look like:
[image: This image is currently unavailable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your `.addField` to :

```
.addFields(
{ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here\n' + 'Some value here\n' + 'Some value here', inline: true },
{ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here\n' + 'Some value here\n' + 'Some value here', inline: true },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make adding files a lot cleaner by using `addFields` in the code that you sent, this will let you add multiple fields at once so you won't have to repeat yourself multiple times

```
//so for example
Embed.addFields(
                  {name:'hi', value:'hello'},
                  {name:'hi', value:'hello'},
                  {name:'hi', value:'hello'}
)
```

This would make it a lot cleaner to put them all in one parentheses, I think it's possible to also remove `name` and `value`

Comment: What I mean by cleaner is not for my code to look cleaner, but for my outcome to look cleaner.